# How to extract the year from a numeric string using Sql/Presto?

Tags: sql, datetime, extract, presto, trino

Hello I'm using SQL through Presto and I am trying to extract the year from the numeric string below and some how group the strings so I can pull by year and not month. The string is not stored as a date, its stored as a number. The below reads January 2019.

```
201901
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide by 100:

```
select floor(num / 100) as year
```

Note:  Presto does integer division.  So if the "number" value is an integer, you can just use:

```
select num / 100 as year
```